# If $|S|>1$, then $M(S)$ is not a group with respect to composition. Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

**Question:** If $|S|>1$, then $M(S)$, the set of all mappings from $S$ to $S$, is not a group with respect to composition. Why?

**My answer:** Any mapping that maps more than one element from the domain to the same element in the codomain will not be invertible; hence, $M(S)$ is not a group. More formally, let $\alpha\in M(S)$ be an arbitrary mapping. Let $\eta,\kappa,\lambda\in S$ be arbitrary elements in $S$ with the condition that $\kappa\neq\lambda$. If $\alpha(\{\kappa,\lambda\})=\eta$ for any $\kappa,\lambda$, then the mapping $\alpha$ is not invertible.

Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: Yes, to be more simple: if the constant map is a bijection from $S$ onto $S$ then $S$ has to contains exactly one element. (if a map isn't bijection then it cannot have inverse with respect of composition)

Comment: @LeonhardtvonM Yes, that may be the *simplest* way of describing the answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's stated in the **question** at the beginning of the question, not in the title (so as to reduce white space). $M(S)$ is just the set of all mappings from $S$ to $S$.

Comment: Sigh, I've been having real reading problems today. Need to nap. @fancynancy

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'd like a nap too. But math...it just can't wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is right. Here is a longer one.

The set $M(S)$ is a *monoid* under composition.

The largest submonoid of $M(S)$ that is a group (its group of "units") is exactly the set of all permutations of $S$.

If $S$ has more than one element, these two monoids do not coincide because not every map $S\to S$ is a bijection. Hence, $M(S)$ is not a group.

If $S$ has $n$ elements, then there are $n^n$ maps but only $n!$ permutations.

If $n\ge2$ then $n^n \ge 2^n > n!$.